# Sphinx indexer returns 1

Tags: php, sphinx

When I try to run sphinx indexer with passthru in php, it returns "1" exit code. What does exit code means?

Answer (score 1):

Here are codes, taken from searchd.cpp:

```
<?php 
/// known status return codes 
enum SearchdStatus_e 
{ 
        SEARCHD_OK              = 0,    ///< general success, command-specific reply follows 
        SEARCHD_ERROR   = 1,    ///< general failure, error message follows 
        SEARCHD_RETRY   = 2,    ///< temporary failure, error message follows, client should retry later 
        SEARCHD_WARNING = 3             ///< general success, warning message and command-specific reply follow 
}; 
?>
```

Your question is very vague, I don't know if this is what you are searching for

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 1 means fatal error. You need to read exact error meaning from indexer's stdout. PHP passthru sending it to the script output.